# Sql assign unique key to groups having particular pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum, amazon-redshift

Hi I was trying to group data based on a particular pattern.

I have a table with two column as below,

```
Name  rollingsum
 A        5
 A        10
 A        0
 A        5
 A        0
 B        6
 B        0
```

I need to generate a key column that increment only after rollingsum equals 0 is encountered.As given below

```
Name   rollingsum   key
  A       5          1
  A       10         1
  A        0         1
  A        5         2
  A        0         2
  B        6         3
  B        0         3
```

I am using postgres, I tried to increment variable in case statement as below

```
Declare a int;
a:=1;

........etc 
Case when rolling sum =0 then a:=a+1 else a end as key
```

But I am getting an error near :

Thanks in advance for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ordering columns because the results depend on the ordering of the rows -- and SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Then do a cumulative sum of the 0 counts from the end of the data.  That is in reverse order, so subtract that from the total:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + sum( (rolling_sum = 0)::int ) over () -
        sum( (rolling_sum = 0)::int ) over (order by ordercol desc)
       ) as key
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a column called `id` to order the rows, here is one option using a cumulative count and a window frame:

```
select name, rollingsum,
    1 + count(*) filter(where rollingsum = 0) over(
        order by id
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) as key
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72c0d0c2c958deb7c2bd6273dfdfd4fa)**:

```
name | rollingsum | key
:--- | ---------: | --:
A    |          5 |   1
A    |         10 |   1
A    |          0 |   1
A    |          5 |   2
A    |          0 |   2
B    |          6 |   3
B    |          0 |   3
```